# Maven dependency that can exclude build number?

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml

Our build process uses a "[major].[minor].[fix]-[build number]" jar naming pattern.

In the maven pom file I want to define a dependency that uses just the "[major].[minor].[fix]" element of this, i.e. it excludes the build number from the dependency mapping.  Can I do this in Maven?

For example: maven project 'A 2.1.0' is using  dependency 'B 3.3.0'.  In project A's maven file I include a dependency on 'B 3.3.0'.

The CI process might be churning out the following the following 'B' JAR files...

```
 B 3.3.0-101
 B 3.3.0-102
 B 3.3.0-103
```

How can I setup my maven POM so that it picks ups the latest build number of 'B 3.3.0', whatever the build number?

Comment: You can't. Simple as that. You _could_ configure it to get the latest version with `<version>LATEST</version>` but that's it. Maven is not intented to be used that way.

Comment: Are you using those dependencies outside an other project or just within a reactor build ?